# Is there a way to prevent passing undefined in my named parameter constructor?

Tags: typescript

I have the following class

```
export class ComponentModel {
    type: ComponentType;
    displayName: string;
    isEnabled: boolean;

    constructor({
        type = ComponentType.defaultComponent,
        displayName = "Component",
        isEnabled = false
    }) {
        this.type = type;
        this.displayName = displayName;
        this.isEnabled = isEnabled;
    }
}
```

When I look at my constructor I notice that you can pass undefined

```
constructor ComponentModel({ type, displayName, isEnabled }: {
    type?: ComponentType | undefined;
    displayName?: string | undefined;
    isEnabled?: boolean | undefined;
}): ComponentModel
```

How can I prevent this? I want to prevent having to check if something is undefined in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`undefined` is permitted because you're assigning default values to the destructured parameters:

```
    constructor({
        type = ComponentType.defaultComponent,
```

will result in a call of `new ComponentModel({})` resulting in a `type` property of `ComponentType.defaultComponent`.

If you want to require all properties in the passed object, remove the default assignments:

```
    constructor({
        type,
        displayName,
        isEnabled
    }: {
        type: // whatever ComponentType.defaultComponent is
        displayName: string,
        isEnabled: boolean
    }) {
```

But there's nothing wrong with default assignment if that's what you want - the properties on the resulting instance will never be undefined.

Comment: Thanks, I see. Are you by any chance aware of any code generation options for constructors with named parameters and public fields? I'm finding myself writing alot of boiletplate code.

Comment: I don't know of any, unfortunately. One thing to consider is - do you *actually* need to put all properties directly on the class instance? Do you actually need a class in the first place, or just a place to store data? If either of those are "no", you can make it a lot simpler by removing the class or by putting the properties onto a single property of the class.

Comment: I noticed that with both interfaces and types you can leave out fields. Which would cause errors in my app. So I opted for a class. But having a field of the type interface might be a good idea.

Comment: *with both interfaces and types you can leave out fields* ? You shouldn't be able to. Eg `type Color = { r: number; b: number; a: number; }; const c: Color = { r: 55, b: 66 };` throws an error. Using a type (or interface) alone should be doable.

Comment: It seems to be running in jsFiddle when it is set to typescript. I tested this beforehand.

Comment: I copy pasted you example into jsFiddle and it does not seem to throw an error.

Comment: JSFiddle does not provide an actual TypeScript environment. It looks like all it does is transpile the code without doing any real type checking. I'd recommend never using it with TS. Use an environment which *does* type-check instead, like with `tsc`, or with VSCode, or the Typescript Playground https://www.typescriptlang.org/play

Comment: Aah I see, my decision was based on that. I'll use Typescrip Playground in the future.